# What does it mean by "bloated" in the following?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was taking a look at some Programming Language Book when I saw the below paragraph:

> The choice of admin tool here is a totally  personal one. I have used
> pgAdmin in its prior iterations, and it was totally fine,  but since
> they moved it to a “web version,” running in its own little webserver,
> I’ve  avoided it. Can’t quite put my finger on why; I think mostly it
> just comes across as  a **bloated** and counterintuitive piece of
> software. It’s a web app that requires the  install of a local
> webserver? Doesn’t “smell” right to me.

As to the paragraph, what's the meaning of **bloated** in this context?

Does the author mean that this software is not as good as they would say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent wrong to say that the software is not as good as it seems.

A bloated software means

> Software bloat is a process whereby successive versions of a computer program become perceptibly slower, use more memory, disk space or processing power, or have higher hardware requirements than the previous version, while making only dubious user-perceptible improvements or suffering from feature creep. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat)

So basically by saying it is a "bloated piece of software" and that it is a "web app that requires the install of a local webserver", means it is a software that is "slightly worse" than what it is supposed to be.